# submit form generated by jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created a simple script to generate a custom form based on uploaded files 
the script work normally with no issues 
the only issue is when submit the created for which is not a part of DOM because its been created by Jquery . 
when i submit it it send null values even it have values .
here is the code

```
﻿$(function(){

    //------------- Plupload php upload  -------------//
    // Setup html4 version
    $("#html4_uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html4', 
        url : '../../assets/dashboard/php/upload.php',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        max_file_count: 15, // user can add no more then 15 files at a time
        chunk_size : '5mb',
        multiple_queues : true,

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
    });

    var uploader = $('#html4_uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info) {
            if (uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('.gradient').hide();

                form    = '<form class="form-horizontal" id="mediaAdd" novalidate="novalidate" method="post">';
                length  = uploader.files.length;
                files   = uploader.files;

                for (var i = 0; i <= length-1; i++) {
                    form+= '<div class="alert alert-success" id="message" style="display:none;"></div>';
                    form+= '<div class="form-row row-fluid">';
                    form+= '<div class="nostyle">';
                    form+= '<div class="row-fluid">';
                    form+= '<label class="form-label span3" for="medianame">عنوان الملف</label>';
                    form+= '<input class="span3 text" name="mediatitle[]" type="text">';
                    form+= '<input type="hidden" name="mediapath[]" value="'+files[i].name+'" >';
                    form+= '<strong style="margin-right:20px;" >'+files[i].name+'</strong>';
                    form+= '</div>';
                    form+= '</div>';
                 }

                 form+= '<div class="form-row row-fluid">';
                 form+= '<div class="span12">';
                 form+= '<div class="row-fluid">';
                 form+= '<div class="form-actions">';
                 form+= '<div class="span3"></div>';
                 form+= '<div class="span9 controls">';
                 form+= '<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn marginR10" style="margin:10px;" >حفظ</button>';
                 form+= '<button class="btn btn-danger">مسح</button>';
                 form+= '</div>';                  
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</form>';
                 $('#multiform').html(form);

                 $('#mediaAdd').submit(function(){
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                             type: "POST", 
                             async: false,  
                             data: $('#mediaAdd').serialize(),
                             success: function(data){
                                alert(data);
                             },
                             error: function(){alert('error');}
                        });

                        return false;
                 });
            }
        });

});
```

and this is the var dumb result from the php file

```
Array
(
    [mediatitle] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [mediapath] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18.jpg
            [1] => 4.jpg
            [2] => 7.jpg
            [3] => 22.jpg
        )
)
```

for the mediapath[] it have values with nor problem because its been given by the script but for the  mediatitle[] it gives empty values ..

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the way you bind your events so you don't have to bother about when their target are added to the dom

something like this will work:

```
var $body=$(document.body); //top parent in the dom 

$body.on("submit","#mediaAdd",function(e) {})
     .on("FileUploaded","#html4_uploader", function//...)
     //...
       ;
```

bind in jquery scope, if you do inside a function chain a `.off(` before with same selector & same event to avoid the event being triggered multiple times